Is it possible to use Msql request with Python 32 bits, using mysql-connector-python and mysq?
I am trying to use python3.10-32bits with mysql on my windows 11 machine.
BUt the package installation is failing.
So i wonder if using mysql with python310-32bit is possible or not?
How can i address this ?
Thank you
Collecting mysql
  Using cached mysql-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (746 bytes)
Collecting mysqlclient (from mysql)
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.6.tar.gz (91 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Using cached mysql-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      # Options for building extension module:
        library_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\lib\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\lib']
        libraries: ['kernel32', 'advapi32', 'wsock32', 'shlwapi', 'Ws2_32', 'crypt32', 'secur32', 'bcrypt', 'mariadbclient']
        extra_link_args: ['/MANIFEST']
        include_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\include\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\include']
        extra_objects: []
        define_macros: [('version_info', (2, 2, 6, 'final', 0)), ('__version__', '2.2.6')]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb\constants
      running egg_info
      writing src\mysqlclient.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\MySQLdb\_mysql.c -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\MySQLdb
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-310\Release\src\MySQLdb
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Dversion_info=(2, 2, 6, 'final', 0)" -D_
_version__=2.2.6 -IC:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb -IC:/mariadb-connector\include -IC:\Users\shoareau\PycharmProjects\test_calprocessing_32bits\venv\include -IC:\Users\shoareau\AppData\Local\Pr
ograms\Python\Python310-32\include -IC:\Users\shoareau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\
ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Pr
ogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Schlumberger\THM\EnvWriter\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Schlumberger\BER\EnvWriter\include" /Tcsrc/MySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-310\Release\src/MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
      _mysql.c
      src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient

I have a python program running on python310-64bits, that handles mysql request.
I wanted to do the smae but with a python310-32 bits.

I would guess that the answer is yes. But because connector does not ship 32bit version by default, you need to compile it yourself. And As seen in your error message, compilation fails because msvc (visual studio compiler) cannot find mysql.h.  On linux this would mean that you are missing -dev package that ships with the headers but on windows, hard to say what you are missing..

but with a python310-32 bits. why? That's the actual problem. Windows 11 is 64-bit only so all wheels are compiled for 64-bit. You gain nothing by trying to use 32-bit Python. Every package will have to be compiled for 32-bit, which means you'll have to ensure your machine can build 32-bit packages

I'm confused.  Are you asking about mysql, mysq, msql or mssql?  You have mentioned 3 out of 4 of these in the Question title ... and you are running on Windows so the 4th is possible too.

@StephenC while it's quite possible the OP is confused about the different products, the question's real problem is trying to use 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS. The error shows an attempt to build mysqlclient, using an outdated Windows SDK version and missing MySQL headers.

I know.  But the OP still needs to write his question properly.

@StephenC indeed. I suspect this is an XY Problem and 32-bit Python isn't needed at all

This question is similar to: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've published the wheels. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/79272298/4788546 for details.
